my window.datalayer is populated with events data, but I see nothing on my google analytics dashboard
I'm using next15 + @next/third-party-libraries for google analytics I correctly set the google Analytics provider
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@next/third-parties/google'
export default function RootLayout ({
  children
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <html lang='en-US' >
      <body className={`font-clash ${firaCode.variable}`}>
        {children}
      </body>
      <GoogleAnalytics gaId='G-XYZ' />
    </html>
  )
}


and here is my event fired with sendGAEvent from '@next/third-parties/google'
 sendGAEvent(
            'event',
            'swap',
            {
              label: recipient === null
                ? 'swap w/o Send'
                : recipient === account
                  ? 'swap w/o Send + recipient'
                  : 'swap w/ Send',
              value: [
                trade?.inputAmount?.currency?.symbol,
                trade?.outputAmount?.currency?.symbol
              ].join('/')
            })

when the event is fired, using window.datalayer on the console I can se the event Argument:
window.datalayer screenshoot
but as soon I go on my Google Dashboard I see nothing
dashboard image
What this can come from?
thanks
I tried to integrade google script provided instead of the GoogleAnalytics component but it's not working, same issue, tried to refactor the event, but as well I have the same problem, I'm ont since 48 hours already and I found no solutions so far

check your network tab. do you see analytics calls there to google's "collect" endpoint?
